# Trouble with setting up cloned scala project - classes not found

Tags: scala, sbt, bitbucket

first of all, I'm a complete programming beginner. So I would really appreciate as detailed answers as possible (step by step explanations preferred, if possible).

I'm working with IntelliJ Idea 14.0.2 and cloned the following repository from bitbucket (I used checkout from version control - mercurial):

https://bitbucket.org/oscarlib/oscar (I especially need the discrete event simulation examples "des-examples" for my master thersis)

My problem is that defined classes are not recognized by other modules and imports are being marked as "unused", even though they should not. Furthermore, the Build code is also full of errors and unused imports.

in this code fragment for example, sbt, de, xerial, sbtunidoc and Build cannot be resolved and all imports are marked as unused:

```js
package oscar

import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._
import java.lang.Boolean.getBoolean
import de.johoop.jacoco4sbt.JacocoPlugin._
import xerial.sbt.Pack._
import sbtunidoc.Plugin._


object OscarBuild extends Build {
```

I guess there have to be some essential libraries missing, but I just can't figure out which ones. I installed the scala plugin and set the project sdk (java 1.7) properly. There is a discription on bitbucket on how to build the project from sbt, but it is not very helpful for me:

https://bitbucket.org/oscarlib/oscar/wiki/oscarbuild

Has anyone already had similar problems? Or would anyone be so kind and try out setting up this specific project and provide an instruction on how to do it?

Thank you very much!!!

Full Build code:

```js
package oscar

import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._
import java.lang.Boolean.getBoolean
import de.johoop.jacoco4sbt.JacocoPlugin._
import xerial.sbt.Pack._
import sbtunidoc.Plugin._


object OscarBuild extends Build {

  
  
  object BuildSettings {
    val buildOrganization = "oscar"
    val buildVersion = "1.2.0.beta"
    val buildScalaVersion = "2.11.0"
    val buildSbtVersion= "0.13.0"

    val osNativeLibDir = (sys.props("os.name"), sys.props("os.arch")) match {
    case (os, arch) if os.contains("Mac") && arch.endsWith("64") => "macos64"
    case (os, arch) if os.contains("Linux") && arch.endsWith("64") => "linux64"
    case (os, arch) if os.contains("Windows") && arch.endsWith("32") => "windows32"
    case (os, arch) if os.contains("Windows") && arch.endsWith("64") => "windows64"
    case (os, arch) => sys.error("Unsupported OS [${os}] Architecture [${arch}] combo, OscaR currently supports macos64, linux64, windows32, windows64")
}

    val buildSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
      organization := buildOrganization,
      version := buildVersion,
      scalacOptions in Compile ++= Seq("-encoding", "UTF-8", "-deprecation", "-feature", "-unchecked", "-Xdisable-assertions"),
      testOptions in Test <+= (target in Test) map {
          t => Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "junitxml(directory=\"%s\")" format (t / "test-reports")) },
      parallelExecution in Test := false,
      fork in Test := true,
      javaOptions in Test += "-Djava.library.path=../lib:../lib/" + osNativeLibDir,
      unmanagedBase <<= baseDirectory { base => base / "../lib/" }, // unfortunately does not work
      unmanagedClasspath in Compile <+= (baseDirectory) map { bd => Attributed.blank(bd / "../lib/") },
      scalaVersion := buildScalaVersion)
  }

  object Resolvers {
    val typesafe = "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
    val artifactory = "Artifactory" at "http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases"
    val sbtResolvers = Seq (artifactory)
  }

  object Dependencies {

    //val scalatest = "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.0.M5b"
    val junit = "junit" % "junit" % "4.8.1" % "test"
    val scalaswing = "org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % "2.11.0-M7"

    // DSL for adding source dependencies ot projects.
    def dependsOnSource(dir: String): Seq[Setting[_]] = {
      import Keys._
      Seq(unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile <<= (unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile, baseDirectory in ThisBuild) { (srcDirs, base) => (base / dir ) +: srcDirs },
          unmanagedJars in Compile <++= (baseDirectory in ThisBuild) map { base =>
           val libs = base / dir
           val dirs = libs // (libs / "batik") +++ (libs / "libtw") +++ (libs / "kiama")
           (dirs ** "*.jar").classpath
          },
          
          unmanagedSourceDirectories in Test <<= (unmanagedSourceDirectories in Test, baseDirectory in ThisBuild) { (srcDirs, base) => (base / dir ) +: srcDirs })
    }
    implicit def p2source(p: Project): SourceDepHelper = new SourceDepHelper(p)
    final class SourceDepHelper(p: Project) {
      def dependsOnSource(dir: String): Project =
        p.settings(Dependencies.dependsOnSource(dir): _*)
    }

  }
  
  import BuildSettings._
  import Dependencies._
  import Resolvers._

  val commonDeps = Seq(/*scalatest,*/junit,scalaswing)
  
 
  TaskKey[Unit]("zipsrc") <<= baseDirectory map { bd => println(bd); IO.zip(Path.allSubpaths(new File(bd + "/src/main/scala")),new File(bd +"/oscar-src.zip"))  }
    
  val hello = TaskKey[Unit]("hello", "hello documentation")
  
  val helloTask = hello := {
    println("Hello World")
  }
  
    
  val printLinprog = TaskKey[Unit]("printLinprog", "printLinProg")
  
  val printLinprogTask = printLinprog := {
    println("base "+baseDirectory)
    
    println(baseDirectory.map { base => base })
  }  
  
  val zipsrc = TaskKey[Unit]("zipsrc","zip the source") <<= baseDirectory map { bd => println(bd); IO.zip(Path.allSubpaths(new File(bd + "/src/main/scala")),new File(bd +"/oscar-src.zip"))  }

  val foo = TaskKey[Unit]("foo","foo task") <<= baseDirectory map { bd => println(bd)}

  val commonTasks = Seq(helloTask,foo,zipsrc,printLinprogTask)
  
  //
  lazy val jacoco_settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(jacoco.settings: _*)
  //jacoco.reportFormats in jacoco.Config := Seq(XMLReport("utf-8"), HTMLReport("utf-8"))
  
  
  lazy val oscar = Project(
    id = "oscar",
    base = file("."),
    //
    settings = buildSettings ++ jacoco_settings ++ 
               packSettings ++ unidocSettings ++ 
               Seq (/*resolvers := sbtResolvers,*/ libraryDependencies ++= commonDeps) ++ 
               sbtassembly.Plugin.assemblySettings ++ 
               commonTasks,
    aggregate = Seq(oscarVisual,oscarCp,oscarCbls,oscarFzn,oscarLinprog,oscarDes,oscarDfo),
    dependencies = Seq(oscarCp,oscarCbls,oscarFzn,oscarDes,oscarDfo,oscarLinprog)) dependsOnSource("lib")    
    
  lazy val oscarCbls = Project(
    id = "oscar-cbls",
    base = file("oscar-cbls"),
    settings = buildSettings ++ jacoco_settings ++ Seq(libraryDependencies ++= commonDeps) ++
         sbtassembly.Plugin.assemblySettings ++ 
         commonTasks,
    dependencies = Seq(oscarVisual)) dependsOnSource("lib")       
    
  lazy val oscarCp = Project(
    id = "oscar-cp",
    base = file("oscar-cp"),
    settings = buildSettings ++ jacoco_settings ++ Seq(libraryDependencies ++= commonDeps) ++
         sbtassembly.Plugin.assemblySettings ++ 
         commonTasks,
    dependencies = Seq(oscarAlgo,oscarVisual)) dependsOnSource("lib")
    
    
  lazy val oscarFzn = Project(
    id = "oscar-fzn",
    base = file("oscar-fzn"),
    settings = buildSettings ++ jacoco_settings ++ Seq(libraryDependencies ++= commonDeps) ++
         sbtassembly.Plugin.assemblySettings ++ 
         commonTasks,
    dependencies = Seq(oscarCbls)) dependsOnSource("lib")     
    
  lazy val oscarDes = Project(
    id = "oscar-des",
    base = file("oscar-des"),
    settings = buildSettings ++ jacoco_settings ++ Seq(libraryDependencies ++= commonDeps) ++ 
          sbtassembly.Plugin.assemblySettings ++         
               commonTasks,
    dependencies = Seq(oscarInvariants)) dependsOnSource("lib")     
    
  lazy val oscarDfo = Project(
    id = "oscar-dfo",
    base = file("oscar-dfo"),
    settings = buildSettings ++ jacoco_settings ++ Seq(libraryDependencies ++= commonDeps) ++ 
               sbtassembly.Plugin.assemblySettings ++ 
               commonTasks,
    dependencies = Seq(oscarAlgebra,oscarVisual,oscarAlgo)) dependsOnSource("lib")       
    
  lazy val oscarLinprog = Project( 
    id = "oscar-linprog",
    base = file("oscar-linprog"),
    settings = buildSettings ++ jacoco_settings ++ Seq(libraryDependencies ++= commonDeps) ++ 
               sbtassembly.Plugin.assemblySettings ++ 
               commonTasks,
    dependencies = Seq(oscarAlgebra)
    ) dependsOnSource("lib")
    

  lazy val oscarAlgo = Project(
    id = "oscar-algo",
    settings = buildSettings ++ jacoco_settings ++ Seq (libraryDependencies ++= commonDeps) 
               ++ commonTasks,    
    base = file("oscar-algo"),
    dependencies= Seq(oscarUtil,oscarVisual)) dependsOnSource("lib")
    
  lazy val oscarVisual = Project(
    id = "oscar-visual",
    settings = buildSettings ++ jacoco_settings ++ Seq (libraryDependencies ++= commonDeps) ++ 
               commonTasks,    
    base = file("oscar-visual"),
    dependencies= Seq(oscarUtil)) dependsOnSource("lib")      

  lazy val oscarInvariants = Project(
    id = "oscar-invariants",
    settings = buildSettings ++ jacoco_settings ++ Seq (libraryDependencies ++= commonDeps) ++ commonTasks,    
    base = file("oscar-invariants")) dependsOnSource("lib")     
 
 
  lazy val oscarAlgebra = Project(
    id = "oscar-algebra",
    settings = buildSettings ++ jacoco_settings ++ Seq (libraryDependencies ++= commonDeps) ++ commonTasks,    
    base = file("oscar-algebra")) dependsOnSource("lib")     

      
    
  lazy val oscarUtil = Project(
    id = "oscar-util",
    settings = buildSettings ++ jacoco_settings ++ Seq (libraryDependencies ++= commonDeps) ++ commonTasks,    
    base = file("oscar-util")) dependsOnSource("lib")       
    

    
  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Double check that your sbt and scala versions are right. Scala can be very finicky with versions. Also the check what versions the plugin supports. If you add a plugin make sure to reload or reimport the project.